# Qual tipo de projeto usar para criar um jogo multiplayer no Construct 2?

Tags: jogos, construct-2

Minha versão do Construct 2 é a r146, e nela o plugin Multiplayer não está aparecendo no "insert new object'.

Qual tipo de project aceita Multiplayer?

Answer (score 3):

A sua versão do Construct 2 é antiga e não possui engine multiplayer.

O engine multiplayer foi incluído na versão: [r164](https://www.scirra.com/construct2/releases/r164)

A solução é você atualizar para uma versão mais nova.

Verifique se sua a versão é a comercial (Personal ou Business), pois, segundo o [site da Scirra](https://www.scirra.com/store/construct-2), a versão gratuita não permite o desenvolvimento de jogos multiplayer.